# "__o" is not declared in Visual Studio 2008 doing ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008

I have been getting this annoying error/bug in Visual Studio 2008 quite a bit when doing ASP.NET MVC.

**"__o" is not declared**

[image: "__o" is not declared]

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the actual code as well as the picture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add this on the page at the top:

```
<%="" %>
```

...So now my ASP.Net content placeholder begins like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%="" %>
```

Quote from: [Mikhail Arkhipov (MSFT)'s WebLog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2006/04/20/580165.aspx)

> In order to provide intellisense in <%= %> blocks at design time, ASP.NET generates assignment to a temporary __o variable and language (VB or C#) then provide the intellisense for the variable when you type in the <%= %> block, similarly to what happens when you type x=.

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed in length on the [ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/p/923745/1266105.aspx). You should be able to find an answer there on the linked thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in code behind file.

Public __o As Object ' VB.net

public object __o ; // C#

[click here to get breif explanation](http://forums.asp.net/p/923745/1266105.aspx)