# The name '__o' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 and opened my asp .net project that I was working on. I'm receiving many errors (all exactly the same) as below:

> Error  CS0103  The name '__o' does not exist in the current context

Well actually I don't have any variables named '__o' and the code works like a charm (error is invalid) but what bothers me is that I'm not able to see when my code really has an error as it goes somewhere in this list and I should check the whole list.

[image]

Comment: [Relating to __o](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975773/o-is-not-declared-in-visual-studio-2008-doing-asp-net) Also might try searching the solution for it. =/

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I found out that if I choose **Build Only** instead of **Build + IntelliSense** the errors (that are related to IntelliSense) will go away.

[image]

**Update 1: The Reason**

The reason that this is happening is that for codes like this:

```
<% if (true) { %>
    <%=1%>
<% } %>
<%=2%>
```

In order to provide IntelliSense in <%= %> blocks at design time, ASP.NET generates assignment to a temporary __o variable and language (VB or C#) then provide the IntelliSense for the variable. That is done when page compiler sees the first <%= ... %> block. But here, the block is inside the if, so after the if closes, the variable goes out of scope. We end up generating something like this:

```
if (true) { 
    object @__o;
    @__o = 1;
}
@__o = 2;
```

The workaround is to add a dummy expression early in the page. E.g.

```
<%=""%>
```

This will not render anything, and it will make sure that __o is declared top level in the Render method, before any potential if (or other scoping) statement.

**Update 2: Getting rid of this error without losing other IntelliSense errors**

Click on the filter button on the top left corner of the error list panel and uncheck the **CS0103** which the error code for the: **The name '__o' does not exist in the current context** and these errors will not be shown anymore and you can still have other IntelliSense errors and warnings:

[image]

Comment: Having the same problem here. I could hide IntelliSense errors, but that seems like brushing it under the rug. Want to trace the problem.

Comment: This is not the fix, like Dan said, that it is just hiding that problem. Plus it would hide all IntelliSense errors, not just that one..

Comment: This dummy workaround (<%=""%>) is excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 32):

After reading the links given in the comments above, it turns out to be how intellisense handles if blocks.

> Mikhail Arkhipov posted an explanation and workaround in the [ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079221/failure)
>   forums:
>
> We have finally obtained reliable repro and identified the underlying issue. A trivial repro looks like this:
>
> ```
> <% if (true) { %>
>     <%=1%>
> <% } %>
> <%=2%>
> ```
>
> In order to provide intellisense in `<%= %>` blocks at design time, ASP.NET generates assignment to a temporary `__o` variable and language
>   (VB or C#) then provide the intellisense for the variable. That is
>   done when page compiler sees the first `<%= ... %>` block. But here, the
>   block is inside the `if`, so after the `if` closes, the variable goes out
>   of scope. We end up generating something like this:
>
> ```
> if (true) { 
>     object @__o;
>     @__o = 1;
> }
> @__o = 2;
> ```
>
> The workaround is to add a dummy expression early in the page. E.g. `<%="" %>`. This will not render anything, and it will make sure
>   that `__o` is declared top level in the Render method, before any
>   potential `if` (or other scoping) statement.

Noting above, [Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079221/failure)'s answer doesn't actually do much harm, other than hiding all intellisense error, which would be known anyway at build time.

Reference: 
http://youku.io/questions/324366/asp-net-mvc-error-name-o-is-not-declared
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f.aspx

Comment: You should put the part about using "<%="" %> at the top of your answer so it stands out.

Answer (score 6):

Declare variable __o in code, like this:

```
public object __o;
```

Be sure to put it in **Master page** (*if you are using one*).

Comment: I don't understand why someone should -1 this answer. It is more elegant than adding <%="" %>.

Comment: this one worked for me (visual studio 2019), .NET 4.8). I couldn't make `<%="" %>` work

Answer (score 5):

> <% response.write(var) %> instead of <% =var %> removes the error
>   without declaring __o as suggested other posts

http://forums.asp.net/p/923745/1266105.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What resolved this problem from its heart for me was to add a dummy expression early in the page.  E.g. <%="" %>. Check out this link for further explanation: https://forums.asp.net/post/1263727.aspx

Comment: This was a temporary resolution, as it resolved it for a moment, then for some reason the error message came back.  Now, even if i add this near the beginning of the page, it no longer resolves the message.

Answer (score 0):

I my old ASP.net MVC project I put this in my master page right at the top and it helped in at least one instance where <%="" %> did not help:

```
<script runat="server" type="text/C#">
public object __o;
</script>
```