# Deleted view in ASP.NET Core causing build errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I deleted a View and now I am getting a build errors:

> The name '__o' does not exist in the current context

on the view that I deleted. I get this exact error on 3 lines.

I did a clean, deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders, recreated the view (as it was before I deleted it), closed and reopened Visual Studio, and still have not been able to get it to successfully build.

Comment: Not sure if it is the same cause, but there are some things to try in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886413/the-name-o-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: @Steve, I did see that one. Sadly it's not just an IntelliSense error, it's an actual Build error for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what happened, but I ended up checking in all my code to my Git repo, deleted the whole Git folder, and then cloned it.

I then did a search for any reference to the view I had deleted and saw that one of my views had a bunch of preprocessor directives that looked like what is in the {View}.cshtml.g.cs files, including file references to my old view. I deleted them from my new view and had a successful build.

I did not see those preprocessors before I deleted my local repo and re-cloned it from Git. So this must have been some very odd behavior by Visual Studio.